# Facebook profile picture doesn't show up Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a profile with Facebook profile picture's and name of the user in Swift. I manage to get them on the ViewController where the login button is located but they don't show up in the Profile ViewController where I need them. Here is the code I use :

For the login page :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
{

@IBOutlet var btnFacebook: FBSDKLoginButton!
@IBOutlet var ivUserProfileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureFacebook()
}



func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        let strFirstName: String = (result.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)!
        let strLastName: String = (result.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)!
        let strPictureURL: String = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!

        self.lblName.text = "Welcome, \(strFirstName) \(strLastName)"
        self.ivUserProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)!)!)
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
{
    let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()

    ivUserProfileImage.image = nil
    lblName.text = ""
}



func configureFacebook()
{
    btnFacebook.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];
    btnFacebook.delegate = self
}

}
```

Here is the code for the Profile ViewController :

```
import UIKit

class Profile: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var profilePicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
    {
        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            let strFirstName: String = (result.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)!
            let strLastName: String = (result.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)!
            let strPictureURL: String = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!

            self.userName.text = "Welcome, \(strFirstName) \(strLastName)"
            self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)!)!)
        }
    }

}

}
```

I think I'm missing a link between the first VC and the Profile VC but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why you are calling  **func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)** function in both VC

Comment: It didn't seem logical to me either but I couldn't manage to call the strPictureURL constant in the Profile VC so I tried to make a second call to the API in the other VC, which is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: you can pass the strPictureURL from ViewController to your ProfileVC using the **func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
@IBOutlet var btnFacebook: FBSDKLoginButton!
@IBOutlet var ivUserProfileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel!
var object: AnyObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureFacebook()
}

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

 self.object = result
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueID", sender: self)

 }

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
{
    let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()

    ivUserProfileImage.image = nil
    lblName.text = ""
}
    func configureFacebook()
    {
     btnFacebook.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];
    btnFacebook.delegate = self
   }


 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
                if segue.identifier == "YourSegueID" {
                    let dvc =  segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2
                       dvc!.object = object // sending facebook data from VC to ProfileVC
                }
            }
```

}

in ProfileVC

```
import UIKit
class Profile: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var profilePicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
var object: AnyObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(object)// your facebook object

print(object.objectForKey("first_name")as! String)
print(object.objectForKey("id") as! String)
print(object.objectForKey("last_name")as! String)

let image =  object.objectForKey("picture") as! NSObject
let data = image.valueForKey("data") as! NSObject
let ProfilepicUrl = data.valueForKey("url") as! String
print(ProfilepicUrl)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, it works, I get the data in the console but I have an issue to display it on my UIImage and UILabel elements on my screen.

Comment: it crashes with an error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" in the "let image =  object.objectForKey("picture") as! NSObject" line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120917/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-theof).